# Why can one not form passive with “wissen/kennen”?

Tags: passive

Basically the title — the grammar book I’m looking at says one can’t form the passive with *wissen* or *kennen*, among other verbs. So

> Er wird von keinem gekannt.
> Das wird nicht bewusst.

wouldn’t work?

Is this because one should instead say

> Er ist von keinem bekannt.
> Das ist nicht bewusst.

?

When does one use *ist* instead of *wird*, if that’s the case?
Danke im Voraus!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*wissen* and *kennen* don't describe a process, but rather a static state, so can't (semantically) use the *Vorgangspassiv*.

Grammatically, you can form the passive with no problems at all:

- Etwas wird gewusst
- etwas wird gekannt

and you could at least form the *Zustandspassiv* of both verbs. Most of that is, however, already covered by the two **adjectives** *bewusst* and *bekannt* (the former, admittedly, with a slightly deviating meaning), so the passive is not impossible, but rarely used.

You could, on the other hand, easily construct valid sentences that use that passive of that verbs, like, for example, in a situation where most pupils failed a test, the teacher would say:

> Das hätte einfach gewusst werden müssen.

So, any passive form of those verbs is really not *impossible*, but unlikely and rare.

Answer (score 6):

##### Why no passive?

Ability to form a passive is not a hard rule: There are verbs that are more able to form passives than others. "Kennen" and "wissen" do allow the passive in some cases. For example, see

> Gekannt und geliebt werden ist das beste überhaupt. 
> To be known and loved is the best thing ever.

Joining with "geliebt" justifies the passive here.

[Zifonun, 1992](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/799/file/Zifonun_Das_Passiv_im_Deutschen_1992.pdf) lists mainly three reasons that make it easier for a verb to have a passive:

- "telic-transformative" (does it need time to reach a result): "wissen" is not a process, it is a state.
- "causative" (does a agent cause a change in the recipient): No. Being known is no change.
- "active" No active action.

Since none of the criteria are met, the passive is rarely used. Also, there is an alternative in "bekannt":

##### bekannt

If you want a passive of "wissen" or "können", generally the solution is to use "ist (jemandem) bekannt". Usually it is not "bewusst", which is more like "aware".

Because "bekannt" takes dative, not "von+Dativ",
your second examples need to be corrected to

> Er ist keinem bekannt. 
> Das ist nicht bekannt.

The sentence

> Das ist nicht bewusst.

without saying who means "It is not concious.", where it might refer to an action. While

> Das ist keinem bewusst.

means "No one is aware of it.", which is a bit different to "It's known to no one."

##### Why ist instead of wird?

"bekannt" and "bewusst" might come from participles, but they behave and are used in every way like adjectives, so they take "sein".

Answer (score 2):

I a native speaker of German, but not a teacher of German as a Foreign Language. So here's my answer, but it's more felt, which sounds right to my ears, and I can't tell what “rule” is behind this. Rules are made up by people who observe and want to explain the language to a stranger. For native speakers, it's more like, I hear something and I just know (from millions of experiences throughout my life) what it should be. So here it is this:

---

**Er wird von keinem gekannt**: This emphasizes that there really is no one who knows him. *He's been hanging around here for a few days, I've spoken to the neighbors, but nobody knows him, nobody knows anything about him.*

**Er ist von keinem bekannt**: I would dare say that is grammatically incorrect. “Er ist keinem bekannt” without “von” would be Official German. That would be how it would be written in a police report, “Er ist keinem Bekannt.” It would also be conceivable that “er ist von keinem bekannt” is an abbreviation of “er ist von keinem bekannt worden”, which would refer to a different verb, “bekennen” (to profess), which doesn’t make sense here.

→ What they probably meant to say: **Niemand kennt ihn.** That would be what I would use.

---

**Das wird nicht bewusst**: Something remains too subliminal to become conscious. Normally one would use this with a personal reference: ***Mir** wurde nicht bewusst, dass …* (Since one typically only recognizes such things by considering the past tense, I actually only know this formulation in the past tense.) / ***Niemandem** wird bewusst, dass, …* (It would be conceivable in a story that the author anticipates knowledge that the characters are not yet aware of at this moment: *Die Gäste feiern ausgelassen, und niemandem wird bewusst, dass ihr Schicksal in diesem Moment bereits besiegelt ist.*)

**Das ist nicht bewusst**: This would express that a thing *could* be known but is not conscious. This is about Known Unknowns (as opposed to Unknown Knowns and Unknown Unknowns. See: [There are known knowns](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns))

Comment: Note that *bekannt* and *bewusst*, even if they somewhat look like participles, are in fact adjectives. So, no passive in the examples using those.

Comment: @tofro Part. Perf. von bekennen ist bekannt.

Comment: @Olafant That's correct. But there's an adjective "bekannt" that has nothing to do with "bekennen" (which has btw a completely different meaning out of the context of this question..